# Infinite Loop in 2D Array in MIPS Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, multidimensional-array, mips, infinite-loop

My project for my comp sci course says that I need to allow a user to input student names, age, and ID into a list, allow the user to swap students from one location to another and print the array. My professor recommended that I implement the list as a 2D array. I am currently working on getting the user input. I created a loop to place the student name in column 1, the age in column 2, and the ID in column 3.

I am what I believe is an infinite loop, meaning my program never branches to the main menu after getting the user input. After writing information for the 10 students, the program continues to ask for student information.

```
#Program 5

.data

studentList: .space 120     #Create space for student information

studentRow: .word 10        #2D array studentList has 10 rows
studentCol: .word 3     #2D array studentList has 3 columns

                #Row 1 holds name, Row 2 holds age, Row 3 holds ID


getListPrompt: .asciiz "Enter the name, age, and ID for 10 students:\n" #Prompt user for student information


mainMenu: .asciiz "Menu: \n\nPress 1 to swap students\tPress 2 to exit the program"

getSwap: .asciiz "Which student do you want to move? "
getDestination: .asciiz "Where do you want to move the student? "

debugNextRow: .asciiz "\nReached next row!\n"       #will be used for degugging purposes

exitMessage: .asciiz "\n\nAh, yes, the sweet release of death..."

.text

main:

#Intro message

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, getListPrompt       #prompt user to enter student information
    syscall

    la $s0, studentList     #$s0 holds the base address of studentList
    lw $a1, studentRow      #$a1 has the row size
    lw $a2, studentCol      #$a2 has the column size

    b getInfo


#start code for user input

getInfo:

    li $t0, 0       #$t0 is our row index
    li $t1, 0       #$t1 is our column index
    li $t3, 0       #$t3 is used to avoid an infinite loop, tracks columns

    writeInfoLoop:      #addr = baseAddr + (rowInd * colSize + colInd) * dataSize

        #$t2 will hold the index

        mul $t2, $t0, $a2       # $t2 = rowIndex * colSize
        add $t2, $t2, $t1       # $t2 = rowIndex * colSize + colIndex
        mul $t2, $t2, 4         # $t2 = (rowInd * colSize + colInd) * dataSize
        add $t2, $t2, $s0       # $t2 = baseAddr + (rowInd * colSize + colInd) * dataSize

        #$t2 now has the index [i, j] where i represents the row and j represents the column

        la $a0, studentList     #Load address of studentList into $a0
        li $a1, 41          #$a1 is the character limit of 41 - 1
        li $v0, 8           #take input
        syscall

        li $v0, 4
        syscall

        addi $t1, $t1, 1        #increment column index, move from [i, j] to [i, j+1]
        addi $t3, $t3, 1        #increment tracker

        beq $t1, $a2, switchRow
        ble $t3, 30, writeInfoLoop  #if $t3 (j) < colSize, loop again

    switchRow:

        addi $t0, $t0, 1        #increment row index
        li $t1, 0           #return to first column

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, debugNextRow        #debugging: prints when moving on to next row
        syscall

        b writeInfoLoop

    b menu                  #branch to menu after getting all inputs

#end code for user input


menu:

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, mainMenu        #Display main menu
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0

    b exit

exit:

#Program done

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, exitMessage
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Why are you doing all that address calculation (that you put into `$t2`) when you never use the result for anything? Also, the instruction sequence `b writeInfoLoop` `b menu` looks like a sure bug; how are you ever going to reach the `b menu` instruction?

Comment: Any code that is located in between an unconditional branch and the next label is what we call [unreachable code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code) or [dead code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code).  It serves no purpose to your program.

Comment: @ErikEidt Theoretically you could reach it using a `jr`, or dynamically generated code in RAM. But yeah, in this case it's dead code.

Comment: @Michael, yes, of course.  But that's beyond where the OP is at right now.

Comment: So should I add I add a no-op between the two unconditional branches?